# git log, отбор коммитов не содержащих определенных слов

Tags: git

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно отсечь коммиты с определенным комментарием? Как отобрать коммиты с комментарием я знаю, так `git log --grep "нужная фраза"`, а вот наоборот как? 
Можно было бы так `git log | grep "нужная фраза" -v`, но я вывожу не просто `git log`, а `git log --name-status`, а файлы выводятся на новой строке и они остаются. Вообще меня бы устроил вариант что б файлы выводились в одну строку с информацией о коммите, тогда я уже грепнуть смог бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начиная с версии 2.4 можно использовать

```
git log --grep=text --invert-grep
```